# Expose application that runs under a docker container

Tags: docker

I'm trying to expose a nodejs application that runs under a docker

`docker run -p 3005:3005 -p 5858:5858 -i -t -v /usuarios centos-nodejs:1.0 /bin/bash`

after that command, I access my application

1. `cd usuarios`
2. `node index`

and then the application is running inside the docker container.

How can I expose a port to access in my browser something like `localhost:5858/my_api_here`

Answer (score 0):

It seems a `nodejs` application is bound to `localhost:5858` only inside a container. That's why you cannot access it via `127.0.0.1:5858` from the host. You need to find a way to bind it to `0.0.0.0:5858`. After that you can access it on `127.0.0.1:5858` from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Following the command below, it works

```
docker run -p 3005:3005 -p 5858:5858 -i -t -v C:\Users\lgermano\Documents
\Repositorios:/opt/rede/workspace centos-nodejs:1.0 /bin/bash
```